# Regex with lookahead does not match in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have composed a regex pattern aiming to capture one date and one number from a sentence.  But it does not.

My code is:

```
txt = 'Την 02/12/2013 καταχωρήθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο της Υπηρεσίας Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. του Επιμελητηρίου Βοιωτίας, με κωδικόαριθμό καταχώρισης Κ.Α.Κ.: 110035'

p = re.compile(r'''Την\s? # matches Την with a possible space afterwards

               (?P<KEK_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) #matches a date of the given format and captures it with a named group
               
               \.+ # Allow for an arbitrary sequence of characters 
               
               (?=(κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.)|(κ\.?α\.?κ\.?:?\s*)) # defines two lookaheads, either of which suffices
               
               (?P<KEK_number>\d+) # captures a sequence of numbers''', re.I|re.VERBOSE)

p.findall(txt)
```

I would expect to return a list with two elements: `'02/12/2013'` and `'110035'`, but instead, it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- `\.+` matches one or more dots, you need to use `.+` (no escaping)
- `(?=(κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.)|(κ\.?α\.?κ\.?:?\s*))(?P<KEK_number>\d+)` will always prevent any match since the positive lookahead requires some text that is not 1 or more digits. You need to convert the lookahead to a consuming pattern.

I suggest fixing your pattern as

```
p = re.compile(r'''Την\s? # matches Την with a possible space afterwards
(?P<KEK_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) #matches a date of the given format and captures it with a named group
.+ # Allow for an arbitrary sequence of characters 
(?:κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.|κ\.?α\.κ\.:?)\s+ # defines two lookaheads, either of which suffices
(?P<KEK_number>\d+) # captures a sequence of numbers''', re.I | re.X)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8cKdFP/2)

**Details**

- `Την\s?` - `Την` string and an optional whitespace
- `(?P<KEK_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})` - Group "KEK_date": a date pattern, 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/` and 4 digits
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.|κ\.?α\.κ\.:?)` - either of

  - `κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.` - `κωδικ`, any char, an optional whitespace, `αριθμ`, any one char, an optional whitespace, `καταχ`, any 1 char, `ριση` and any 1 char (but line break char)
  - `|` - or
  - `κ\.?α\.κ\.:?` - `κ`, an optional `.`, `α`, an optional `.`, `κ` a `.` and then an optional `:`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<KEK_number>\d+)`  - Group "KEK_number": 1+ digits

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1K8gBH):

```
import re
txt = 'Την 02/12/2013 καταχωρήθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο της Υπηρεσίας Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. του Επιμελητηρίου Βοιωτίας, με κωδικόαριθμό καταχώρισης Κ.Α.Κ.: 110035'
p = re.compile(r'''Την\s? # matches Την with a possible space afterwards
(?P<KEK_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) #matches a date of the given format and captures it with a named group
.+ # Allow for an arbitrary sequence of characters 
(?:κωδικ.\s?αριθμ.\s?καταχ.ριση.|κ\.?α\.κ\.:?)\s+ # defines two lookaheads, either of which suffices
(?P<KEK_number>\d+) # captures a sequence of numbers''', re.I | re.X)
print(p.findall(txt)) # => [('02/12/2013', '110035')]
```